# Is Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath) Always "Safe"?

Tags: asp.net, url

I have the need to redirect back to the current page minus any query arguments.

I just found `Request.Url.AbsolutePath`, which looks like it provides just the ticket to pass to `Response.Redirect()`.

It seems to work on my dev machine okay. Does anyone know of any potential problems redirecting to the value of this property? It's hard to confirm it's "safe" in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a problem if you "re-written" the URL internally. For example, the user request "/team.aspx" but internally you transfer execution or rewrite the url as "/page.aspx?id=137".

Personally, I prefer to use the Request.RawUrl (which is always local) and you can strip the query-string.

Getting rid of the host part of a request is not an issue because HTTP Redirect can be path on Absolute Paths ("/foo/bar") and the browser will preserve the protocol, port and hostname.

Comment: I read your first paragraph several times but still don't quite understand. If the user requests `/team.aspx`, then I would expect `Request.Url.AbsolutePath` to return `/team.aspx`. Where does `/page.aspx?id=137` come from?

Comment: @Marcelo - But he is not rewriting the url.

Comment: Jonathan, if you use any form of URL re-write the URL on AbsolutePath is not the same URL on RawUrl. RawUrl is what was sent via HTTP Request and it's what the user sees on his browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Request.Url.OriginalString.

Absolute path gets rid of the host part of the URL.

Take a look at this: http://wdevs.blogspot.com/2009/03/url-properties-of-request-to-aspnet.html

Comment: But `OriginalString` includes the query string. I know I could strip it off, but what's wrong with redirecting to `Request.Url.AbsolutePath`? As long as I'm redirecting to the same domain, I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: @JOnathan Wood - Misread your post, you are right, there are no issues with what you are trying to do.  If you don't want the actual query parameters then use `Request.Url.AbsolutePath`